# Verdana font 8.5pt size with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, fontspec, fontsize, font-encodings

I have a very simple MWE where I try to use Verdana 8.5pt size:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=8.5pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setromanfont[SizeFeatures={Size=8.5}]{Verdana}


\begin{document}

Testing Verdana font with \textit{italic text}, \textbf{bold text}, and \emph{emphasized text}.

\end{document}
```

which gives me:
[image]

There are a few issues here. First, when I copy/paste the result, the font size of the first part of the text is not 8.5 but 8 (but I really need 8.5). Also, you see the italic, bold, and emphasized text gets font size 10. Am I missing optional arguments to `\setromanfont` or I need a different class?

Comment: The `fontsize=8.5pt` option is not recognized or otherwise processed by the `article` document class. (The only three fontsize-related options of the `article` class are `10pt` (the default), `11pt`, and `12pt`.) What you'll need to do is to re-define not only `\normalsize` but also `\small`, `\footnotesize`, `\scriptsize`, `\tiny`, `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, etc.

Comment: You must use one of the KOMA-classes if you want to use this syntax. E.g. `scrartcl`.

Comment: I changed to `scrartcl` and still gives me 8pt font (although the issue with the italic, bold, and emphasized text changing back o 10pt is gone.

Comment: How do you know that you got 8pt?

Comment: Copy/paste in MS Word.

Comment: Do you trust MS word?

Comment: Good point. I opened the file with Adobe Acrobat, and I got 8.47pt!

Comment: Even without Koma (`scrartcl`), you can use `\setmainfont[Scale=...]` or `\fontsize`. Keep in mind, however, that a LaTeX `pt` is 1/72 inch, and Word’s “points” are not the same size.